The minimal eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix
Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix, and I want to show that for: $\epsilon>\lambda_{min}(A)$:
$$A+\epsilon I>0$$
where $\lambda_{min}(A)$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.
My reasoning is as follows:
first note that since $A$ is symmetric there exists $U$ s.t $U^TU=I$ and $A=U\Lambda U^T$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with $A$'s eigenvalues.
So let's take some $v$, and prove for it that: $v(A+\epsilon I)v^T >0$.
So I am writing it down as: $vAv^T+\epsilon vv^T=vU\Lambda U^Tv^T+\epsilon vv^T=u\Lambda u^T+\epsilon vv^T = (1)$. Now choose $v$ such that: $\Lambda u^T= -\lambda_{min}(A) u^T vv^T/uu^T$.
So we get: $(1)= (\epsilon-\lambda_{min}(A))vv^T>0$.
Now since I proved it for one such $v$, it follows that $A+\epsilon I>0$, since $\sup_{v} v(A+\epsilon I)v^T >0$.
Am I right in my reasoning?
Thanks in advance for your input.

Don't you mean $\epsilon > - \lambda_{min}(A)$?

@QiaochuYuan , no. This is as it's written in the text.

Unless you have some strange sign convention about the meaning of $\lambda_{min}(A)$, this is false as written; take e.g. $A = -I$, so that $\lambda_{min}(A) = -1$, and e.g. $\epsilon = - \frac{1}{2}$.

@QiaochuYuan how would you prove it with a minus sign as you want to correct it?

Just use (or prove) that if $B$ is a symmetric matrix then $B$ is positive-definite iff its eigenvalues are positive, and use the fact that the eigenvalues of $A + \epsilon I$ are $\lambda(A) + \epsilon$.
